# High availability clustering in netbsd

Tags: cluster-computing, lvm, netbsd

We need to do high availability clustering on one of our system. I have found sum of the tools like HA-Lvm from RedHat, but it is not supported with netbsd. We need a scenario where the applications should run optimally in active/passive (failover) configurations where only a single node that accesses the shared storage is active at any one time. There are other tools on netbsd like corosync but they create replication of the storage. We want the storage to be shared by the two systems. If one goes down then another comes up to provide the uninterrupted services on the same storage.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear but you should have a look at `ucarp`. It is the failover system used by NetBSD and OpenBSD, similar (but more simple) to Heartbeat or Keepalived on Linux.

https://www.netbsd.org/docs/guide/en/chap-carp.html